# How to remove data from a memory stream with a specific starting string

Tags: c#, memorystream

I have to remove data from a Memorystream starting with a specific string and all the way to the end of the stream before writing this to a word doc template.

I have tried the following, but when i convert stream to string it is giving some encoded random codes. I am not able to find specific string in the converted string.

```
        Memorystream ms;
        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(ms);
        string st = rdr.ReadToEnd();
        if (st.IndexOf("EmployeeDetail") != -1)
        {
            int start = st.IndexOf("EmployeeDetail");
            string toWrite = st.Substring(0, start);
        }

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(st);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to [specify an encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor)

Comment: Consider streaming you content in, rather than using `ReadToEnd` (yeah, string recognition will be more work, but it will likely be faster and will definitely use less memory)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you need:

```
void Main()
{
    var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

    var inputStream = new MemoryStream();
    inputStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("Hello, World!"));

    var outputStream = CreateWithReplace(inputStream, ", World", encoding);
    var outputString = encoding.GetString(outputStream.ToArray());
    
    Console.WriteLine(outputString);
}

private MemoryStream CreateWithReplace(MemoryStream inputStream, string textToRemove, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
{
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    inputStream.Position = 0;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputStream, encoding))
    {
        string inputText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        int start = inputText.IndexOf(textToRemove);
        if (start != -1)
        {
            string outputText = inputText.Substring(0, start);
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputStream, encoding))
            {
                writer.Write(outputText);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            inputStream.WriteTo(outputStream);
        }
    }
    return outputStream;
}
```

It outputs `Hello` to the `Console`.